# running command with expect

Tags: shell, expect

I have created a shell script which will automate login to a remote machine.
But I need to automate the execution of commands or shell scripts also along with this script.
What modification do I need to do with shell script for creating a directory(for example!) in the remote machine ?

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect
set login "root"
set addr "10.3.2.0"
set pw "root"

spawn ssh -t $login@$addr
expect "$login@$addr's password:"
send "$pw\r"
interact
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to find an Expect tutorial or read the "Exploring Expect" book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add statements to your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set login "root"
set addr "10.3.2.0"
set pw "root"

spawn ssh -t $login@$addr
expect "$login@$addr\'s password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "~" ; # put here string from your server prompt
send "mkdir some_dir\r"
interact
```

Comment: Can you be more concrete? What error did you get? Have you changed the expect statement to your server prompt?

Comment: Its worked !!.I thought it didnt work since it diplayed `mkdir some_dir` in shell.But the directory was created !

Answer (score 0):

or if you do not have info about the prompt how will look like commands with `spawn` can be invoked one by one separated with `interact`:

```
spawn command1
interact
spawn command2
interact
spawn command3
interact
```